# LINQ Union objects with same Base Class

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities, union

I'm trying to create a list of all my objects from several lists of objects using Union.

```
Return Chart.AnnotativeNodes.Union( _
         Chart.DecisionNodes.Union( _
           Chart.EndNodes.Union( _
             Chart.StartNodes.Union(Chart.WorkCenterNodes))))
```

The above line gets an error because I can't union `List(of AnnotativeNode)` with `List(of DecisionNode)`. Each list defined like `List(of EndNode)` or `List(of StartNode)`, but each class inherits from the base type Node.

Is there a possible way to union these to get a result of `IEnumerable(of Node)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, you should be able to do it like this:

```
Return Chart.AnnotativeNodes.Union(Of Node) _
           (Chart.DecisionNodes.Union(Of Node) _
               (Chart.EndNodes.Union(Of Node) _
                   (Chart.StartNodes.Union(Of Node)(Chart.WorkCenterNodes))))
```

That should work due to generic covariance in .NET 4. Otherwise, you could just call `Cast(Of Node)` on each of the collections.

I suspect your code can be written more readably though, as:

```
Return Chart.AnnotativeNodes.Union(Of Node)(Chart.DecisionNodes) _
                            .Union(Of Node)(Chart.EndNodes) _
                            .Union(Of Node)(Chart.StartNodes) _
                            .Union(Of Node)(Chart.WorkCenterNodes)
```

If you *need* the union-ing to happen in a particular order, you can mess with it - I haven't bothered, as Union is meant to be a set operation in the first place.