# How to combine 2different IQueryable/List/Collection with same base class? LINQ Union and Covariance issues

Tags: linq, union, covariance

I am trying to combine (union or concat) two lists/collection into one. The two lists have a common base class. e.g. I've tried this:

```
        IQueryable<ContractItem> contractItems = myRepository.RetrieveContractItems();
        IQueryable<ChangeOrderItem> changeOrderItems = myRepository.RetrieveChangeOrderItems();

        IQueryable<ItemBase> folderItems = contractItems.Concat<ItemBase>(changeOrderItems);
```

But am getting the LINQ error 
            DbUnionAllExpression requires arguments with compatible collection ResultTypes.

Anybody know how to do this properly? The only thing I could google was another StackOverflow question:
[LINQ Union objects with same Base Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556671/linq-union-objects-with-same-base-class)

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `Cast` operator:

```
IQueryable<ItemBase> folderItems = contractItems
        .Cast<ItemBase>()
        .Concat(changeOrderItems.Cast<ItemBase>());
```

The answer to the other question works for LINQ to Objects, but not necessarily for LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL.

Alternatively, you can convert to LINQ to Objects by calling `AsEnumerable`:

```
IQueryable<ItemBase> folderItems = contractItems
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Concat<ItemBase>(changeOrderItems);
```

However, take care in LINQ to Objects; `Concat` would work without any overhead (iterating through both collections from the database), but `Union` would pull one of the collections entirely from the database and then iterate through the other.

Comment: Thank you for the very fast response. I tried the cast operator, but get this error: Unable to cast ...LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types". Any thoughts on this? Thank you.

Comment: You can try replacing `Cast` with `OfType`. Is `ItemBase` an actual Entity base type?

Comment: I updated the answer with a LINQ-to-Objects approach that will definitely work, if we can't get it working through LINQ-to-Entities.

Comment: I also tried the OfType, I get this error: Unable to cast... LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types". However, I think you a point -- my base class is not an actual Entity, just a common base class to hold common properties. Since I'm working with IQueryable, there's no way for LINQ/Database to translate the queries ... so I might have to find a way to explicitly "cast" (i.e. create a new collection of ItemBase) and then return the collection 'AsQueryable'. Any further advice would be appreciated...

Comment: Ah, yes. I wouldn't expect LINQ to Entities to deal with non-entity base classes. Use the `AsEnumerable` approach that I added to my answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! It really is time for me to dive deep into the .Net 4.0 support for co-variance and contra-variance. Just as you typed up the answer, I saw that IEnumerable supported co-variance but other things like IList do not... so thanks a bundle again! --- btw, small fix to your solution -- if the return type is IEnumerable, but if you want it as an IQueryable, then add ".AsQueryable" to it.

Comment: this should work as well  contractItems
        .Cast<ItemBase>()
        .Concat(changeOrderItems);