# Casting derived class to base class using LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two database tables, one to hold *completed* items and another to hold *incomplete* items. Both tables are identical in structure. There are some cases where I would like to quest just one of these tables, but other cases where I would want to query the concatenation of both tables.

**Classes**

```
public abstract class SomeBase
{
    public int Id {set;get;}
    public string Item1 {set;get;}
    public string Item2 {set;get;}
}
public class A : SomeBase
{
}
public class B : SomeBase
{
}
```

**Mapping (Fluent API)**

```
public class SomeDatabase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As {set;get;}
    public DbSet<B> Bs {set;get;}
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("ATable", "SomeSchema");
        }
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("BTable", "SomeSchema");
        }
    }
}
```

Using this setup, I can query both tables just fine individually like so

```
var db = new SomeDatabase();
var a = db.As;
var b = db.Bs;
```

When trying to combine the two, I can't quite figure out the syntax. One solution in the answer below involves casting it using `.AsEnumerable` but that isn't quite what I'm looking for since it evaluates immediately.

```
db.As.AsEnumerable().Concat<SomeBase>(db.Bs);
db.As.Cast<SomeBase>().Concat(db.Bs.Cast<SomeBase>());
```

How can I concatenate two derived classes that are identical on the database site?

EDIT:
At the lowest level, I am getting these errors

```
db.As.Cast<SomeBase>();
Unable to cast the type 'Test.Models.A' to type 'Test.Models.SomeBase'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

db.As.OfType<SomeBase>();
'Test.Models.SomeBase' is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types.
```

Related question: [How to combine 2different IQueryable/List/Collection with same base class? LINQ Union and Covariance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614989/how-to-combine-2different-iqueryable-list-collection-with-same-base-class-linq)

Comment: Have you tried `Cast<T>()` or `OfType<T>()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply define a

```
DbSet<SomeBase> Bases { get; set;}
```

property to access all instances of the base class. The framework should combine the query the right way (union) to include the instances from both tables.

For more details check out e.g. this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx

(You use the TPC inheritance strategy)

Comment: Totally forgot about that one. Using the base class DbSet. Simple!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on this? I simply added this to my mapping and got an error regarding no Primary Keys. I added a statement to map the PK and then got this error
`The type 'A' cannot be mapped as defined because it maps inherited properties from types that use entity splitting or another form of inheritance. Either choose a different inheritance mapping strategy so as to not map inherited properties, or change all types in the hierarchy to map inherited properties and to not use splitting`

Comment: Try to remove the other 2 DbSets. You could use Bases.OfType<A> and Bases.OfType<B> respectively to get the results from one table only.

Comment: Hmm, this seems like it should work. I previously had many areas where I used `db.As` to get items of type `A`. Removing the 2 DbSets have created ~ 40 errors. I'll work on fixing those and then I'll let you know if everything works. If this turns out to the be the solution, I can't help but to think that querying a base class seeming strange... Perhaps I should use a different naming convention for this scenario

Comment: Put together a test project so to test this method. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

maybe there is some more elegant way, but union should do it i guess:

```
db.As.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Item1, x.Item2 } )
.Union(db.Bs.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Item1, x.Item2 }));
```

if you want to include some fields from As and some fields from Bs then it should look like:

```
db.As.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Afield, Bfield = null } )
.Union(db.Bs.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Item1, x.Item2, AField = null, x.Bfield }));
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it would probably work since anonymous types will be used. Though, the table I am actually working on has 30+ fields, and using this method would surely take up an unreasonable amount of space :-/.

Comment: since you are using TPT (which means separate tables in SQL) i think union is unavoidable. Although you could use reflection to get all the fields and create an expression tree, but certainly it takes even more effort and space

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var concatenatedSet = db.As.Local.OfType<SomeBase>().Concat(db.Bs.Local.OfType<SomeBase());
```

Comment: `db.As.Local.OfType<SomeBase>()` does not error, but yields no results.

Comment: Though I know LINQ pretty well, I do not know EF, but let's dig a bit. OfType<SomeBase>() filters out everything that is not of SomeBase. So the question is wether or not the collection is empty or if the items are not instances of type class A Can you check the type? db.As.Local.Select(t=>t.GetType().FullName and see what type these elements have?