# How to do union between two IQueryables where the first query has different type of the second

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two queries, where the first type is inheriting the second type.

I need doing union between two queries, how can I do it?

For example:

```
public class FirstType
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
}

public class SecoundType : FirstType
{
    public int C {get; set;}
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual IQueryable<FirstType> GetQuery()
    {
        return db.Car.Select(v => new FirstType() { A = v.Column1, B = v.Column2 });    
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{       
    public override IQueryable<FirstType> GetQuery()
    {
        // Here, I get the first query with the base result.
        var query1 = base.GetQuery();

        var query2 = db.Car.Select(v => new SecoundType() { A = v.Column1, B = v.Column2, C = v.Column3 }); 

        // The error occur here.
        return query1.Union(query2);
    }       
}
```

When I do the Union between two queries, occur the following error:

> DbUnionAllExpression requires arguments with compatible collection
>   ResultTypes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine 2different IQueryable/List/Collection with same base class? LINQ Union and Covariance issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614989/how-to-combine-2different-iqueryable-list-collection-with-same-base-class-linq)

Comment: I did see this awnswer, but when I try do cast, ocurr an error because the types not are primitives: "Unable to cast the type 'SecoundType' to type 'FirstType'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the collections must be compatible in number and type of elements, about the only thing you could do is add another element C which is NULL to the query1 before you Union it to query2. Just off the top of my head, so you need to try it out in Visual Studio, maybe something like this:

```
var query1 = base.GetQuery().Select(v => new SecondType() { A = v.Column1, B = v.Column2, C = null });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solution solved my problem. But, exists a better way that do mapper all properties?

Comment: I am sure I could make this better and more general purpose. Without having Visual Studio open, this is just an idea of what has to happen to allow a Union. I'm sure given enough time I could write a generic "Unioner" that would magically merger together different shaped results, but it's probably best to use Select() to shape the two outputs how you want them before you Union them.