# Entity framework - eager loading and inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have following entities

```
class EntityBase
{
    public virtual NavPropType NavPropBase {get; set;}
}

class ChildEntityA:EntityBase
{
    public virtual ChildNavPropTypeA NavPropA {get; set;}
}

class ChildEntityB : EntityBase
{
    public virtual ChildNavPropTypeB NavPropB {get; set;}
}
```

I want to load all of them in one query utilizing eager loading of navigation properties.

```
context.EntitiesBase.Include(e => e.NavPropBase).ToList();
```

This will load them all. However, only `NavPropBase` will be preloaded.

I tried concatenation, but it does not work.

```
var r1 = context.EntitiesBase.OfType<ChildEntityA>
    .Include(e => e.NavPropBase)
    .Include(e => e.NavPropA);

var r2 = context.EntitiesBase.OfType<ChildEntityB>
   .Include(e => e.NavPropBase)
   .Include(e => e.NavPropB);

var r = r1.Concat(r2).ToList();
```

I found similar questions dated several years ago. And it seems that it was not possible at that time. Has anything changed since that? I wonder why such functionality has not been implemented (any technical issues?). I am also not sure why concatenation does not work (at the same time `context.EntitiesBase.ToList();` returns the list of all child entities without problems).

Comment: I think I found a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614989/how-to-combine-2different-iqueryable-list-collection-with-same-base-class-linq) to your question. The answer proposes to use `Cast` extension method as well.

Comment: The casting works, but only without Include. So, it will not resolve my issue.

Comment: What do you mean  with " only works without Include"?, Include is an extension method of `IQueryable<T>` and that interface ineriths from `IEnumerable<T>`. You can call `Cast` extension method after that

Comment: I mean that when you add Include, the Cast will cause runtime error. Thus, it will not work as expected.

Comment: Are `ChildNavPropTypeA` and `ChildNavPropTypeB` inherited from `NavPropType`?

Comment: @Javad No, they are absolutely different types.

Comment: @octavioccl The error:"A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'EntityBase' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'NavPropA'."

Comment: Have you tried marking the nav props as virtual?

Comment: The problem is `Cast` extension method is been included at the time to translate your query to SQL. Add `AsEnumerable` extension method to switch to Linq to Objects as I show in my answer to call `IEnumerable<T>.Cast` instead of `IQueryable<T>.Cast`

Comment: The idea is to try to use LinqToEntities to minimize database trips. Yes, with LinqToObjects everything is easy. ))

Comment: @LazyCoder Actually, in my real code the nav properties are virtual. I guess I need to update this in my question

Comment: **You absolutely should be using properties not fields**  `public virtual ChildNavPropTypeA NavPropA;` -> `public virtual ChildNavPropTypeA NavPropA { get; set; }`.

Comment: @Erik, yes, sorry. Again, I just wrote this for brevity of the question. In reality, I am using the properties (and it does not resolve the issue)